# How to use swiftmailer send email with html/php template

Tags: php, email, swiftmailer

I want to use swiftmailer to send a report on a daily basis. I am able to send a test email for testing but I would like to use an email template for the report. This is what I tried.

```
// Create the mail transport configuration
$transport = Swift_MailTransport::newInstance();

// Create the SMTP configuration
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance("smtp.gmail.com", 465, 'ssl');
$transport->setUsername("user_id");
$transport->setPassword("password");

// Create the message
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance();
$message->setTo(array(
        "firstname.lastname@gmail.com" => "First"));
$message->setSubject("This email is sent using Swift Mailer");
$message->setBody("$email_content", "text/html");
$message->setFrom("test@gmail.com", "Swiftmailer Test");

// Send the email
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
$mailer->send($message);
```

What I did is create a variable called $email_content which returns all of the content of the url (which actually calls a function to grab data from DB to populate some tables on the page).

```
//display data from db on the page
$email_content = file_get_contents("http://localhost/test/get_content.php");
```

However, when I open the email, it is able to display the table with the data but it doesn't display it properly like in the original url. Is it possible to get the email to look close to the url or at least decent with proper formatting?

Comment: This script `http://localhost/test/get_content.php` return whole site code, or maybe it's only part of the site? Probably there are missing some css, thats why your table looks different? I can only guess, you have to provide more info, e.g what's under `http://localhost/test/get_content.php`. And if i can suggest you something, try to use engine template to generate your e-mail content e.g Twig or Smarty, it`s easier to use :)